# How to send multiple emails getting User data in the view - Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to figure out how could I send multiple emails with a custom 'User Name' or relevant data related to a user.

I was using BCC to send a bulk list of user like this:

```
Mail::bcc($emails)->send(new Comunications($data));
```

This works fine, but... What if I need to render my email with data of the current email?

I know, I should loop through $emails array and call to Mail facade each loop.

Guys, this is not very powerful... If I have more than 50 emails to send, will take a while and sometimes I got this error:

Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.0 Requested action not taken: too many emails per second

Yes, probably its because I am testing with Mailtrap but I don't want to worry about it in the future.

This is what I suppose to do now :(

```
foreach ($sending_to_array as $send){
    $user = User::where('email', $send['email'])->first();
    if(!empty($user)){
        Mail::to($send['email'])->send(new Comunications($datas, $user));
    }
}
```

Well, I don't like it.

What you think will be the best solution for this?

Maybe add a Cron job and run it as a queue?

Comment: its always better to use queue to send emails, and the error message u got it placed there by the smtp server to prevent spam.

Comment: Agree with MekjkrhG use queues for sending bulk emails.